# How do I access my app listing in App Store without iphone?

Tags: app-store

So, my app is approved and now I'd like to check what does listing look like in App Store. Is there way to do it without iPhone?

Comment: Theres a app store website isn't there? Android has one. Also, almost definitely off topic here.

Comment: This isn't a programing question.

Comment: Theres a app store website isn't there? - there is no, only kind of outdated index of apps

Comment: Goto [itunesconnect.com](https://itunesconnect.apple.com) from where you uploaded the app in store, click on the app, from App Information tab -> click on View on App Store -> Thats the link can be opened in any web browser no iPhone required..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it can take up to 48 hrs for your app to appear in all stores world-wide.

In iTunes Connect, you will find the **direct link** to your app. Depending on the browser (Safari vs. Chrome/Firefox/IE), first the iTunes Web Preview should show your app's store listing. From there you can view it directly in iTunes (if it's installed on your machine.)

[image]

To check if your app is available in all territories, go to "Pricing and Availability" and check for the right settings there. (Available in all territories)

Answer (score 2):

You can go to iTunes (Both Mac and Windows PC has supported) application and find your app.

There you can check how your app looks like in iPhone.

One more possibility: "https://itunes.apple.com/app/id[Your_APP_ID]"

Ex: https://itunes.apple.com/app/id424562537

Comment: i do that, but iTunes constantly prompting "The item you've requested is not currently available in the Russian Store, but it is available in the U.S. Store. Click Change Store to view this item". When i'm clicking "ok, change store", it just popping up again.

Comment: Yes. You need U.S store apple ID to view that then. Instead I have updated one more possibility in the answer. Try that.

Comment: direct urls don't work. I did switched to US store, it doesn't really helped. Error message is different. Whatever, looks like it's just a delay between the moment when app has been marked as published and when it will be actually published